# fscanf() seg fault Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access, scanf

> ```
>  16     char* input = (char*) argv[1];
>  17     FILE *fp = fopen (input, "r");
>  18     if( fp == NULL)
>  19     {
>  20         printf(" reading input file failed");
>  21         return 0;
>  22     }
>  23     fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
>  24     int file_size = ftell(fp);
>  29     rewind(fp);
>  30     int i;
>  31     int totalRun;
>  32     char * temp;
>  33     char* model;
>  34     char* example;
>  36     fscanf(fp,"%d",&totalRun);
>  37     fscanf(fp,"%s",model);
> ```

Above is my code I get this error at line 37 "fscanf(fp,"%s".model)"

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory. Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5fc00730 0x00007fff8db20bcb in __svfscanf_l ()

What can cause this ?? I looked into *fp in gdb. before reading totalRun _offset = 0 and after reading _offset = 4096. content of totalRun was correct ("3"). I only read one line and why is offset 4096? Also what is _blksize referring to in FILE.

Thank you

Comment: No memory is allocated for `model`. i.e. do malloc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for `model`, it is an uninitialised pointer. Also ensure `fscanf()` does not read beyond the array assigned to `model`. If `model` does not need to by dynamically allocated then just use a local array. For example:

```
char model[1024];
if (1 == fscanf(fp, "%1023s", model))
{
}
```

*Always* check the return value of `fscanf()`, which returns the number of successful assignments, otherwise the program will be processing uninitialised variables if the call to `fscanf()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `model` is not initalized. You must allocated memory for it before it can be used in the `fscanf()` method. You can do in two ways:

1. Statically - `char model[1024];`
2. Dynamically - `char * model = (char*) malloc(1024);` Don't forget to use `free()` to deallocate the buffer once you are done.